# Configure OData property to have type Date instead of DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata, odata-v4

I'm following [this "guide"](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#12-01-DateAndTimeOfDayWithEF) on how to expose `Date` (not `DateTime`) in your `ODataController`

However I don't quite get how I should implement the `.AsDate()` extension method

```
public static class PrimitivePropertyConfigurationExtensions 
{ 
  public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration AsDate(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property)
  {…}

  public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration AsTimeOfDay(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property)
  {…}
}
```

What goes in the `...` place?
Am I missing something obvious?

None of the methods on `property` seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As per `Date & time mapping with EF`

`2 Fluent API`

```
public static class PrimitivePropertyConfigurationExtensions 
{ 
  public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration AsDate(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property)
  {
    property.HasColumnType("date");
  }

  public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration AsTimeOfDay(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property)
  {
    property.HasColumnType("time");
  }
}
```